# SSH authentication methods questions

Tags: ssh, authentication, ssh-keys, public-key-encryption

These days i look at the SSH protocol and iam trying to figure out how the password and public key authentication methods really work.

In password authentication, i know that the client encrypts the credentials with the host public key adn server decrypts with its private key. ( if it is actually correct)

But in public key, when the client tries to connect to the server, how does the authentication take place and how the man in the middle attack is prevented with this method?

In addition, in password authentication, how does the Strict checking works?

Sorry for maybe asking silly questions, but i am a beginner.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

> In password authentication, i know that the client encrypts the credentials with the host public key adn server decrypts with its private key. ( if it is actually correct)

No, that's not correct. The server's keypair is not part of the user authentication process at all – it is verified independently in a much earlier phase. In addition to that, *neither* of the two keypairs is used to encrypt any data: both are only used for signing.<sup>1</sup>

Instead, SSH configures the encryption layer *before anything else happens*, and all messages from that point – whether authentication or regular data – are encrypted using it in the same way. So it's actually more similar to sending a plain password over HTTPS.

The overall process is:

1. Key exchange:

   - The server and client perform a [DH or ECDH key exchange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange) to generate a session key.
   - To avoid MITM attacks, the server also uses its host key to attach a digital signature along with the DH key-exchange reply.
   - More details in [RFC 4253 section 8](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4253#section-8).
2. The server and client start using symmetric encryption (usually AES) using the generated key. Every single packet from now on will be encrypted using AES.
3. User authentication:

   - If the client chooses `password` authentication, it just sends the entered password as-is, without any public key operations. (The password is still secured by the general SSH encryption layer.)
   - If the client chooses `publickey` authentication, it receives a random "challenge" from the server, then replies with a digital signature of that challenge. The server verifies the signature.
4. Finally, the client requests an interactive shell (or some other service) to be opened.

---

<sup>1</sup> (Well, technically not always true – there *exist* key-exchange methods that use encryption, they're just never used in general practice.)

Comment: So the host public key will be used from the client to sign the packets to be sent during the whole process? And what is the point in signing? i mean because the client uses a public key to sign and the public key is known to everyone.

Comment: No, the client does not use it to sign anything. During key exchange, the client _verifies_ the signature that the server made using its host private key. (The private key is always needed to make signatures; the public key is only used by the recipient for verification; and there are no exceptions to that.)